# Shopify Dynamic Sections No Longer Showing After Theme Transfer

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I built a custom Shopify theme under the Partners program under "Development Stores".

There are a bunch of dynamic "sections" I setup. I transferred this theme to a client store. After the transfer, they no longer appear though and the only way to update the site is under the config/settings_data.json.

Where should I look to start debugging to get them to appear? I'm a little stuck. Thoughts? Attached is screenshots of exactly what I'm talking about.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you added content to sections via the "Customization" process on the development store you're showing in screenshots, you weren't making changes to that development store's theme -- you're just adding content in that development store's database that's processed by the theme you'd created/installed.

There's two solutions:

1) Recreate all of the section content on your client's store.

2) Simply transfer ownership of the development store you created to your client. Aside from saving you a lot of time, it'll also mean Shopify will send you a cut of your client's Shopify monthly subscription fees.